# What happened to EN World's D&D Lifeboat?

Tags: online-resources, en-world

A while ago when the WotC forums were getting shut down, EN World started up [an Emergency Evacuation Lifeboat](http://www.enworld.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?538-WotC-Emergency-Evacuation-Lifeboat) in an attempt to preserve all the important material and handbooks various parts of the D&D community relied upon. It's recorded in our [our meta list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5452/1204).

The lifeboat is now gone, though, and the link we had for it is broken without any explanation or redirect.

What happened to the lifeboat and the materials inside it? Where did they go, if anywhere? Where should I be looking if I want to find those rescued materials now?

Comment: There was a web site that was aggregating all that stuff.  Last I recall they captured my optimization docs on Weapons and armor enchantments for the 3.5 system.  I had the same user name.  Let me see if I can dredge them up with teh Googles.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Enworld Lifeboat is gone... But the content remains!

The Lifeboat Subforum on Enworld was merged with the main "Charop" forum where posts have prefix tags for editions. All of the curated lifeboat content made it (i.e. not every single charop post, but rather those deemed valuable). There is a [handy post listing all of these guides](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?472893-4E-Character-Optimization-WOTC-rescue-Handbook-Guide) in categories with links as well as a link to the Wayback Machine internet archive of the forums if you are looking for something that was not specifically saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can find 3.X content archived in list format on the [Giant in the Playground Boards](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forum.php), in the [Index of 3.X WotC Threads](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?444041-Threads-from-the-Wizards-forums). Content from the soon-to-be-defunct Minmax and Brilliant Gameologist websites is also being archived on GitP, in the [Index of Minmax and Brilliant Gameologist Threads](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?527170-Index-of-Minmax-Brilliant-Gameologist-Threads).